# why are my Div Tags are being pushed to the left by a few pixels?

Tags: css, html, tags, css-float

I'm trying to build a website for some coursework and my two middle columns are being pushed over to the left for some reason. The header, nav bar and footer all align vertically but the two floated divs in the middle are being forced to the left.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nJ0UB.jpg]

**HTML**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Churches Of Norwich</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="site.css"> 
</head>

<body>
     <div id="bg"> 
        <div id="content">
            <div id="headboxspacer"></div>
            <div id="head-box">Churches of Norwich</div>
            <div id="navbar" style="float: none">
                <div id="tabs">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="map.html">Map</a></li>
                        <li><a href="churches.html">Churches</a></li>
                        <li><a href="comments.html">Comments</a></li>
                        <li><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="container" style="overflow:hidden;width: 100%">
                <div id="homeboxleft" style="clear: both">Testing</div>
                <div id="homeboxright" style="clear: both" >Right</div>
            </div>
            <div id="footer"> footer </div>
            <div id="bottomspacer"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
#content {
width: 1200px ;
height: max-content;
margin-left: auto ;
margin-right: auto ;
}

#headboxspacer{
height:50px;
width:100%;
}

#head-box{
background-color: #003651;
height: 120px;
width: 100%;
padding: 10px;
margin: 5px;
text-orientation: inherit;
font-family: sans-serif;
font-size: 65pt;
color: #FEE7BE;
font-style: normal;
text-align: center;
}

#navbar{
height: 50px;
background-color: #003651;
width: 100%;
margin: 5px;
padding: 10px;

font-family: sans-serif;
font-size: 20pt;
color: #FEE7BE;
font-style: normal;
text-align: center;
text-decoration-line: underline;;
width: 100%;
} 

#tabs ul {
margin: 0 ;
padding: 0 ;
list-style: none ;
display: inline ;
}

#tabs ul li {
margin: 0 ;
padding: 10px ;
display: inline ;
text-align: center ;
list-style: none ;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif ;
}

#tabs li a {
color: #FEE7BE;
background-color: #003651 ;
padding: 8px ;
text-decoration: none ;
display: inline ;
} 

#tabs li a:hover {
color: gainsboro ;
background-color: #003651 ;
}

#container{
width: 1200px;
}

#homeboxleft{
background-color: #FEE7BE;
height: 500px;
width: 50%;

float: right;

margin: 0px;
opacity: 10%;
filter:alpha(opacity=10);

text-orientation: inherit;
font-family: sans-serif;
font-size: 10pt;
color: #003651;
font-style: normal;
text-align: center;
}

#homeboxright{
background-color: #FEE7BE;
height: 500px;
width: 50%;
float: left;    
margin: 5px;
text-orientation: inherit;
font-family: sans-serif;
font-size: 10pt;
color: #003651;
font-style: normal;
text-align: center;
}

#mainbox{

background-color: #FEE7BE;
height: 500px;
width: 100%;
opacity: 0.6; 
}

#footer{
background-color: #003651;
height: 120px;
width: 100%;
padding: 10px;
margin: 5px;
text-orientation: inherit;
font-family: sans-serif;
font-size: 65pt;
color: #FEE7BE;
font-style: normal;
text-align: center;
clear: both;
}

#bottomspacer{
height:100px;
width:100%;
}
```

Comment: try removing all margins and paddings set to your floating elements - that could easily be the issue. (btw doesn't it get confusing naming an element you're floating left as "homeboxright"?)

Comment: [jsBin](http://jsbin.com/uzovuw/1/)

Comment: checkout the new edits http://jsfiddle.net/zHBhs/2/

Comment: And what did your DOM inspector tell you?

Answer (score 1):

because the padding of the navbar is added to the width of the navbar.

you have to use the box model solution with an inner div
http://css-discuss.incutio.com/wiki/Box_Model_Hack#Box-in-a-box

then you have the same widths and appearance in all browsers

Comment: Exactly. To clarify, `#homeboxleft` is in the correct position - flush with the right side of `#container`. It's `#navbar` that is causing the "misalignment", by being too wide.

Answer (score 0):

Your "container" which holds the two columns is set to "width =100%".
It means that the div will spread on the entire width of the page.

Try deleting this width attribute, and beside that delete all float attributes.

Answer (score 0):

I have also attached a screenshot.

and this is the fullscreen preview of the fiddle:

> **http://fiddle.jshell.net/zHBhs/2/show/**

I think your problem is the inline css here:

```
<div id="homeboxleft">Testing</div>
<div id="homeboxright">Right</div>
//-------------------^-------------just removed the clear:both inline css here
```

and in your this css class just removed the margin property:

```
#homeboxright{
    background-color: #FEE7BE;
    height: 500px;
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    margin: 0; //  <------------------made margin for all sides to 0
    text-orientation: inherit;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 10pt;
    color: #003651;
    font-style: normal;
    text-align: center;
}
```

try this and see if this solves, checkout the fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/zHBhs/2/

do some work on these css classes as well:

```
#head-box{
    padding:0;    // change paddings to 0
    margin: 5px 0; // just apply to top and bottom margins
}

#navbar{
    margin: 0;      // change paddings to 0
    padding:10px 0; // just apply to top and bottom margins
}

#footer{
   margin: 0;      // change paddings to 0
   padding:10px 0; // just apply to top and bottom margins
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Get both of the sides, left and right in a main div. Then apply this css:

```
#maindiv{
overflow:hidden;
border-bottom:1px solid rgba(200,200,200,0.3);
border-top:1px solid rgba(200,200,200,0.3);
}
#left{
width:60%;
float:left;
overflow:hidden;
}
#right{
overflow:hidden;
}
```

Note: The right div will be attached with left one, If you want to float it to right, Apply float:right; to it. But float to only left is suggested :)

An [Example for both sides](http://jsbin.com/ilahat/2/) using the above trick.